# OpenSSL vulnerability on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running Elastic Beanstalk with Tomcat 8.5 on the latest EB platform version (3.3.9 as of this writing). There is a security vulnerability in the version of OpenSSL that comes pre-installed in the EC2 image:

```
[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4 ~]$ openssl version        
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

> **CVE 2019-1559**
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2 prior to 1.0.2r is vulnerable to a 0-byte record padding oracle attack which could allow a remote attacker to decrypt data passing over the network.

There are no newer openssl versions when searching with `yum`, so how am I supposed to mitigate this threat? I also don't want to install an openssl version that may be incompatible with the services running (apache, tomcat, etc.).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to resolve this? It's becoming a much more crucial issue with the LetsEncrypt intermediate certificate debacle.

Comment: @jeffdill2 According to AWS Support: Amazon Linux has its own repositories, package lifecycle, polices and versioning. Each package (openssl) comes from the project upstream source code (version 1.0.2k), but **Amazon Linux modifies them, includes customization, patches, security fixes, etc.**
So essentially the installed version of openssl, which comes from an AWS repo, includes the latest CVE patches despite reporting an older version - 1.0.2k.

Comment: To check the specific modified/patched version of 1.0.2k you are running, you should be able to run `rpm -q openssl`. For more detail (to see your patched version vs. the most updated patched version available through yum) you can run `yum list openssl`